# Top Questions of the Week #10

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into post 10 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and it's contents.

Answer (score 8):

[What's different between Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+C in Unix command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/262942/whats-different-between-ctrlz-and-ctrlc-in-unix-command-line)

Mark has once again managed to get massive rep for a great explanation of a pair of 'simple' Linux commands.

> <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is used for suspending a process by sending it the signal `SIGSTOP`, which cannot be intercepted by the program. While <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is used to kill a process with the signal `SIGINT`, and can be intercepted by a program so it can clean its self up before exiting, or not exit at all.

Comment: I know the answer is mine (but that's only why I remembered it), but why stop with explaining the difference in *nix when they're also slightly different in Windows -> http://superuser.com/q/214239/39366

Comment: Nobody's going to stop your from writing it @DMA ;-)

Comment: Ha, I stepped right in to that one, didn't I... I don't mind taking this up if it is the selected post (it's about time I wrote something for the blog, after all), but only if I can add the CSS that makes `<kbd>` items into pretty looking buttons to the blog's style sheet, so I can use them in my post. :P (*Joking aside*, if I do write this post I would genuinely like to do that; answering on SU has made me mildly fond of the `<kbd>` keys...)

Comment: You have my permission to add the awesome <kbd> keys to the CSS @DMA **if** you write the blog post :P

Answer (score 6):

[Speed comparison between USB 2.0, USB 3.0 and SATA and Firewire…](https://superuser.com/questions/138845/speed-comparison-between-usb-2-0-usb-3-0-and-sata-and-firewire)

> Which is fast, faster, fastest? I would appreciate a slowest to fastest list including USB 2.0, USB 3.0, FireWire 400, FireWire 800 and eSata.

Comment: Are you planning on testing these yourself? ;-)

Comment: @IvoFlipse I was thinking this is one of the tests for the SU Super PC.